# Assign init arguments automatically in decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to assign all arguments passed to `init` to the class. I cannot get the arguments, nor the class `self` (the `self` that `init` gets passed as first arg):

```
class unpack_arguments(object):

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()



class SomeObject(object):

    @unpack_arguments
    def __init__(self, one=1, two=2, three=3, four=4):
        pass


# At this point, you can do
#
# obj = SomeObject()
# obj.one # 1
# obj.two # 2
# obj.three # 3
# obj.four # 4


obj = SomeObject()
```

I try to find things but can't find the class instance of SomeObject or the key names like `one`, `two`, etc:

```
ipdb> kwargs
{}
ipdb> args
self = <__main__.unpack_arguments object at 0x1077a3f60>
args = ()
kwargs = {}
ipdb> self.f
<function SomeObject.__init__ at 0x1077a06a8>
ipdb> dir(self.f)
['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
ipdb> self.f.__defaults__
(1, 2, 3, 4)
ipdb> self.f.__kwdefaults__
ipdb> self.f.__kwdefaults__
ipdb>
```

Comment: Can you please describe the bigger problem you're trying to solve this way? Have you tried making your decorator a function — it's sort of easier to reason about?

Comment: not exactly the same thing, but for a similar pattern, look at the `attrs` module (on pypi)....

Comment: I'm trying to assign any kwargs given to any class init in the decorator. I don't mind either way I just never use function decorators, they're more confusing

Comment: A decorator can only see the actual parameters passed to the decorated function - defaults for missing parameters are an internal detail of the function.  And since you never actually CALL the decorated function, the default parameters never even exist at all.

Comment: I swear I did this a year ago. Maybe I made a class and subclassed it i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pythonic way to do it is to use `**kwargs`:

```
class SomeObject(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)


obj = SomeObject(a=1, b=2, c=3)

print(obj.__dict__)
```

as you may see representation of object is:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

As you need base class: 
here is "dummy" implementation:

```
class SomeObject_with_init(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, name, value)

    def my_name_is(self):
        return (self.__class__)


class SomeObject1(SomeObject_with_init):
    pass


class SomeObject2(SomeObject_with_init):
    pass


obj = SomeObject1(a=1, b=2)

obj2 = SomeObject2(test='1', test2='2')

print(obj.__dict__, obj.my_name_is())
print(obj2.__dict__, obj2.my_name_is())
```

Output here will be:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2} <class '__main__.SomeObject1'>
{'test': '1', 'test2': '2'} <class '__main__.SomeObject2'>
```

Comment: That's the goal but I want a decorator or at least a subclass

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this, although I prefer [Arseniy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1446154/arseniy) solution or using a metaclass instead of decorating `__init__`.

```
def unpack_arguments(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        cls = args[0]
        cls.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class SomeObject(object):
    @unpack_arguments
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = 'SomeObject'


s = SomeObject(a=1, b=2, c=3)
print (s.a)
print (s.b)
print (s.c)
print (s.object)
```

Returns:

```
1
2
3
SomeObject
```